# Use Data-Type as URL Parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a photo gallery with these 2 different view options: "grid-mini" and "list-medium" switchable using **data-types**. Like this:

`<a href="#" title="Grid View with Mini Thumbnail" data-type="grid-mini" class="grid-mini-link current"></a>`

`<a href="#" title="List View with Medium Thumbnail" data-type="list-medium" class="list-medium-link"></a>`

Is there a way to link to a specific view using a parameter in the URL?
For example, let's say I want photo gallery 1 to display "list-medium" by default, can the URL look like this?

`http://www.sitename.com/gallery1?data-type=list-medium`

The site is using PHP (WordPress)- here's a demo with the views: http://demo.dedepress.com/detube/category/hd/

Comment: Have you tried that, because it will work. I mean, you will need other code to handle the URL parameter value, but what you show is fine.

Comment: You need to do this on the server, what language does it use ?

Comment: You have to pass it like you have, and then read it, and simulate a click in Jquery...or do it on the server.....

Comment: When you click those links does your url read  http://www.sitename.com/gallery1#grid-mini  ?

Comment: You would at least need an onload handler to check for the query string parameter "data-type" and trigger a click on the corresponding button

Comment: Sorry adding "#list-medium" at the end of URL didn't work. The site is using PHP - here's a demo with the views: `http://demo.dedepress.com/detube/category/hd/`

Comment: That's probably because the `#` symbol means something in a url. Try url encoding the value first.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<a href="#" title="Grid View with Mini Thumbnail" data-type="<?php echo $_GET['data-type']; %>" class="grid-mini-link current"></a>
```

You'll probably need to add some validations before that.